# How to have select and textfields appear inline and scaling upon scaling the parent container?

Tags: html, css, forms, inline

In my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j0zwabqv/) i show a form devided into two parts (horizontally). The left part is the problematic one. There are a select element in line with two textfields sharing the available width percentally. What i'd like to have is to give the select and the middle textfield a defined percentual width and have the right textfield to take rest to always span up to the right container border. This layout must remain behaving like this upon scaling the container. Also, the select element must remain readable. At the moment its content is getting partially hidden upon scaling.

I cannot figure the proper formatting to achive this.

Here's my code:

```
<style>
.unseen {
    display: none
}
form {
    background: maroon;
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
}
[class*="span5"] {
    background: olive
}
[class*="span7"] {
    background: pink
}
#salutation {
    width: 12%;
    min-width: 50px
}
#firstname {
    width: 30%
}
#lastname {
    width: 40%
}
</style>

<div class="container" id="page">
   <div class="row-fluid" id="page_content">
      <section class="form row-fluid" id="page_content">
         <div class="row-fluid">
            <form class="form-horizontal form-validate">
               <div class="span7">
                  <fieldset class="well-small">
                     <legend></legend>
                     <div class="control-group">
                        <div class="control-label">
                           <label id="salutation-lbl" for="salutation">Full Name</label>
                           <label id="firstname-lbl" for="firstname" class="unseen">First Name</label>
                           <label id="lastname-lbl" for="lastname" class="unseen">Last Name</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="controls">
                           <select id="salutation" name="salutation" class="fullname salutation">
                              <option value="Mr." selected>Mr.</option>
                              <option value="Mrs.">Mrs.</option>
                              <option value="Ms.">Ms.</option>
                           </select>
                           <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" value="Max" placeholder="forename" />
                           <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" value="Mustermann" placeholder="surname" />
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </fieldset>
               </div>
               <div class="span5">
                   <h2>Other content</h2>
               </div>
            </form>
         </div>
      </section>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried to solve your question in the best possible way but not exactly as you wanted for the first part of the question as percentage widths won't always work properly since bootstrap is constantly changing the parent container's width. So, I have written a jquery function that will calculate the desired width of these input text boxes and dynamically add them as their respective css widths. This function along with some other minor html/css tweaks will fix your problem.

1. **HTML** - Changed the bootstrap form class from `form-horizontal` to `form-inline` which better suits the requirements.

   `<form class="form-inline form-validate">`
2. **CSS**

   - Added a fixed width of 65px that keeps the `select` element readable even with the longest possible option. (mrs.)
   - Removed percentage widths from `#firstname` and `#lastname` selectors as we'll be adding those via jquery.
   - And finally added a `!important` to the `display` property of the `unseen` class (required when switching to bootstrap `form-inline` class)

     ```
     .unseen {
         display: none !important;
     }

     form {
         background: maroon;
         margin: 0;
         display: flex;
     }

     [class*="span5"] {
         background: olive;
     }

     [class*="span7"] {
         background: pink;
     }

     #salutation {
         width: 65px;
     }
     ```
3. **JQUERY** - Here's the jquery function that does all the trick. This function calculates the available width for the textboxes to fit in with default padding

   ```
   function resizeFormElements() {
       /*
           Calculating the available width for the two text boxes by subtracting the 
           => main control container width 
            - the width of the selector element
            - 4 * default_bootstrap_margin_of_3px between input elements (two input elements so both left and right margins)
            - 4 * default_padding_of_6px of input text elements as per bootstrap.min.css line 238 (two input elements so both left and right padding)
            - 1 (to not get affected by truncated values)
       */
       var avail = parseFloat($(".controls").width()) - parseInt($("#salutation").css("width")) - 4 * 3 - 4 * 6 - 1;
       $("#firstname").css("width", avail / 2);
       $("#lastname").css("width", avail / 2);
   }

   $(window).on("resize load", function () {
       resizeFormElements();
   });
   ```

Here's a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shikhar/08npynfL/8/) of the above solution.

Comment: First of all thanks a bunch for taking the time and create this solution. It works like charme. What i wonder however, is there no way at all to solve this kind of problems with only CSS via flexbox and transitions?

Comment: Hmmm. The [flexbox](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/) is something that has been constantly changing over time and can't still be considered as standard (latest revision being 25th March, 2014). Even though many browsers have adopted it quickly, its still not fully supported for IE11. Having said that, I'll definitely give it a go.